# Trajectory of an object when asymmetrical forces are acting on it

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, simulations, rocket-science

I'm trying to code a game that uses physics...but I don't how to figure something out:

If I have a 2x2 square (in any unit), with two thrusters/jets whatever you want to call it, on the back, each 1x1 in size...

```
 _ _
|_|_| <-- 2 1x1 Squares
|_|_| <-- Other 2 1x1 Squares 
| | | <-- 2 Thrusters
```

if I turn both of the thrusters on, it will move forward. If I only turn one of them on though, I know it will move in a circle, but how do I find how big this circle will be? I'd appreciate a not very complex solution.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. It will not move in a circle, because it will be accelerating in the angular direction (perpendicular to the centre of the circle). To move in a circle, the thrusters would have to be applied from the sides, and calculated to apply the correct amount of turning depending on the velocity and the level of thrust.

Comment: Shouldn't it move in a circle because the side with the thruster on will move more forward then the side with the thruster off causing it to turn. This will keep on repeating making it move in a circle. If it doesn't move in a circle, then what shape will it move in?

Comment: @Undefined It is important to note that we can solve for the exact trajectory for the center of mass and calculate the angular acceleration of the body(provided that the gravity exists and a few more assumptions). But the center of mass would not follow a circular path, but a much more complicated path. I would try not stick with your case but i would like to improve the model. I would post an answer in a while..

Comment: the trajectory had been derived with a lot of assumptions to make the math easier as much as i can..i would give an elaborate explanation once you respond..

Comment: I looked at your graph but I can't understand the formulas or equations. I don't know much physics and this math is too complex for me.

Comment: I also wanted to do this problem in a 2d, horizontal plane, so there won't be any gravity.

Comment: If the rocket is in space, the only way it can propel is by ejecting mass(burn fuel) out in a specific direction which would propel  the rocket in the countor direction...i think that's pretty easy to do, check out the below answer so that you could get some idea about how that could be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the rectangular block(so called rocket's body) of mass $m=1$ with height $h=8.4$ and width $\ell=4.2$ staying at rest in a planet where $g=0.4$ (I just put pure numbers but it should be understood that they are in proper units). Consider the rocket applying a thrust for half of it's bottom's surface area(very big thruster though!), it's preasumed that the mass of the rocket does'nt change and fairly remains constant(This assumption can be fair in a game, but in real life you probably know that a rocket burns tons of fuel to propel forward). Hence at time $t=0$ we have a body like the below one, Note that the thrust force with respect to the rocket is also assumed to be constant but
you can set it as a variable if you want your rocket to change it's acceleration.

[image: Physics.SE rocket]

Now by applying Newton's second law to the vertical direction, $$F\cos\theta-mg=ma_y$$
Note that the effective reaction force $F$ which is placed $\frac \ell4$ distance left to the center, directly accelerates the center of mass because the rocket is rigid. Also note that $F$ is a function of $\theta$, the angle which the rocket's base makes with the horizontal, sort of like this,

[image]

The body turns on one side because there is an effective torque about the center of mass which is given by, $$\tau = F\frac {\ell}{4}$$ the body rotates about it's center of mass because the moment of inertia about the axis passing through the center of mass is minimum according to parallel axis theorem.

Further,
$$\tau=I\alpha=  F\frac {\ell}{4}\\
\alpha =  F\frac {\ell}{4I}
$$

Also note that the only force which propels the center of mass in the horizontal direction is $F\sin\theta$, or
$$F\sin\theta=ma_x$$

Now, the only information which says that how $\theta$ varies is given by the angular acceleration, if you remember from your kinematics course you probably know that the same holds true for rotation too, that is,
$$
\theta = \theta_0 + \frac {\alpha t^2}{2}\\
\text{But, since}\,\,\theta_0 = 0\\
\theta =\frac {\alpha t^2}{2}  
$$

Now we have complete information describing the motion of the center of mass,

> $$
> a_x = \frac {F\sin\frac {\alpha t^2}{2}}{m}\\
> a_y = \frac {F\cos\frac {\alpha t^2}{2}}{m} - g\\
> $$

Initial position and Initial velocity is zero in both the directions, hence the information of the position could be obtained by integrating the above equations twice, which you probably mentioned as complicated math, but the core idea is extremely simple!

Solving those integrals are definitely pain in the neck hence i preferred desmos, now  i think you could understand what are those equations in this [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rk8wpmhasv), also since the motion is complicated i just approximated the trajectory for an interval of $0<t<1$ , you can extend that if you want with a bit of research.

All these had been done accurately because you asked for a physics based game, I really don't think games use really perfect physics but a very approximate and intuitive version of it!

Edit: I actually used a square(cube) in the original graph hence the moment of inertia was $I=\frac {ml^2}{6}$, but for a rectangle it should have been $I=\frac {m(l^2+h^2)}{12}$. We could observe that the trajectory is not that circular but very steep because we are applying it right from the bottom of the rocket which produces less turning effect, as one of the comment mentions, we have to apply thrust from the sides to have significant turning effect. Anyone if interested can improve the trajectory by choosing the correct value of constants. For instance, increasing the width would improve the turning effect..

See the trajectory here - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rk8wpmhasv

$\theta$ as a function of time,
$$\theta(t) =\frac {(F\frac {\ell}{4I}) t^2}{2}$$

Here's a free tip, make your rocket rotate about the COM with the given theta as a function of time, then just feed the information about $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the COM with a parameter $t(time)$ given by the equations
$$x = \frac {kpt^{4}}{4}\\
y=\frac{kqt^2}{2}$$
This would give an effect that the rocket is tilting and moving, eventhough you know that you feeded information of translation and rotation seperately! Hope you could get it!

Make sure that the period of turning is'nt too large because these equations are valid only for time interval lower than one second, it's because when you have only one thruster on for too long the body would flip and fall.

Comment: Also the body whirl around in complicated path in a sufficiently large amount of time.

Comment: Why does the rocket rotate around its center of mass and not some point off to the right?

Comment: In fact, that's one way to define a rigid body! If a rigid body is not constrained to rotate about a given axis, it will rotate about it's center of mass, because just like current and water, rigid bodies prefer to rotate about an axis which provides least resistance to rotate! The proof may be complicated but i think it's okay for you to accept this result..

Comment: The [appendix20A](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/readings/MIT8_01F16_chapter20.pdf) of this mit paper gives the proof.

Comment: One last thing, how do I find how much the rocket rotates?

Comment: I think you ask for theta as a function of time, i added it in the end of the answer, you must adjust the constants for whatever rate you want your rocket to rotate

Comment: I added some tips in the answer

Comment: Thanks very much! It will take a while for me test the equations, but they seem like they will work.

Comment: Oops!! I added the velocity equations instead!! i will change it! Thank god that i saw it..

Comment: What do k, p, and q stand for?

Comment: see graph of all the equations, i actually approximated complicated equations to simple polynomials so that they can be integrated easily

Comment: click on that left circle on 'velocity' to view the *actual* graph

Comment: open approximation folder to view the approximated velocity equations...u should integrate it to get the position

Comment: i think it's a good idea to brush up your math skills on side, so that u can be comfortable with ur work...a friendly advice from my side

Comment: To be honest, I never studied physics and math in depth, I'm more of a coder. If you wouldn't mind, I'm a bit confused on which equations to use, so could you clear that up?

Comment: I don't know what exactly your confusion is? You could edit your question regarding your confusion

Comment: I'm confused about the last two equations in your answer. What are they for and what are p and q equal to? I saw what k equals in the desmos graph.